# What is wrong with my broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, service, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to make a broadcast receiver that will activate an activity when it receive a specific sms.
this is my code for my broadcast receiver:

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

    public class ringMuhPhoneBR extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras == null)
                return;

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

                Intent it = new Intent();
                it.setAction("com.services.aiks.smsReader")
                        .putExtra("get_ring", sender + ":" + body);
                context.startService(it);
            }
        }
    }
```

I need it to start the service smsReader which has this code

```
  package com.services.aiks;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.os.Vibrator;
    import com.events.aiks.rmpActivate;
    import com.sharedPref.aiks.SharedPref;

    public class smsReader extends Service{

        AudioManager am;
        Vibrator vb;
        SharedPref sp;

        String msgWhole;
        String msgContent;
        String msgSender;
        int maxVolume;

        String rmpk;
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
            am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            vb = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            sp = new SharedPref(this);

            loadPrefs();

            msgWhole = intent.getStringExtra("get_ring");
            msgWhole = msgWhole.replace("\n", "");
            msgContent = msgWhole.substring(msgWhole.lastIndexOf(":") + 1,         msgWhole.length());
            msgSender = msgWhole.substring(0, msgWhole.lastIndexOf(":"));

            try{
                if(rmpk.equalsIgnoreCase(msgContent)){
                    Intent it = new Intent(smsReader.this, rmpActivate.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

        public void loadPrefs(){
            rmpk = sp.strLoadPrefs("RMPK", "scream");
        }
    }
```

the problem is even if I send the correct keyword, the rmpActivate wont start. Ive also tried removing the condition that check if the correct keyword was received and still get no result. Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Comment: Seems like you forgot to register your broadcast receiver.

Comment: how do I do that? or where do I do that. Thanks.

Comment: Read here: "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html"

Comment: this was my receiver in the manifest
`<receiver 
     android:name="com.broadcastreceiver.aiks.ringMuhPhoneBR" >
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>`

Answer (score 0):

in your Manifest file please register your Broadcast.

```
<receiver android:name="Yourpackagename.ringMuhPhoneBR" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.services.aiks.smsReader" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

hopefully it should work for you.

Comment: in my manifest file i have `<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />`

Comment: should I add the android:name to another <action></action>?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that the problem was in Android version. It didnt work in 4.2.2 but when i tried it in 4.0.3 this working silk as smooth. xD
Edit: its working in both version. Working in emulator but not in real device. Im so sad.